# Can sharepoint user profile customized and set security?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, user-profile, user-profile-service, user-accounts

Can sharepoint user profile edit page customized?

I am planning to customize the user profile page, and have a function to generate a new UPN for users, and update it on AD. Is it possible?